# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when i try to link with twitter from ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to link with Twitter from ruby on rails application

on one server it works fine, BUT for some reason I am getting:

```
 "500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this 
  website, then please read this web application's log file and/or 
  the web server's log file to find out what went wrong."`
```

Ruby Version: `ruby 2.4.0`

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
```

Call back Url : https://www.server.one/auth/twitter/callback

can anyone help

**An OAuth::Unauthorized occurred in #:**

**403 Forbidden**

---

### **Request:**

### * URL        : https://www.server.one/auth/twitter

- HTTP Method: GET
- IP address : 103.255.4.38
- Parameters : {}
- Timestamp  : 2019-04-28 15:38:10 UTC
- Server : ip-172-31-41-28
- Rails root : /var/www/server/releases/20190428153431
- Process: 18080

Comment: have you checked your application's log as it says?

Comment: exepction raised 
An OAuth::Unauthorized occurred in #:

  403 Forbidden



-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : https://www.server.one/auth/twitter
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : 103.255.4.38
  * Parameters : {}
  * Timestamp  : 2019-04-28 15:38:10 UTC
  * Server : ip-172-31-41-28
  * Rails root : /var/www/server/releases/20190428153431
  * Process: 18080

Comment: Found this https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/issues/131. You might have already gone through.

Comment: thanks let me check

Comment: no luck , for now

Comment: Are you sure your OAuth application tokens are valid and correctly configured?

Comment: Yes same configuration are running fine on Server2.com

Comment: Found an issue , when i turn off load balancer it works fine,